# Reviewboard/SVN post-review errors: repository path is not in the list of known repositories

Tags: svn, review-board

I'm having difficulties with creating a new review entry in Review Board automatically through a checkin in Subversion (SVN). I've created a post-commit hook which, when run manually gives the following exception:

```
Failed to execute command: ['c:\\python25\\Scripts\\post-review', '--repository-   
url=file:///Repository/svn/TestProject', '--user
=reviewmanager', '--password=########', '-p', '--submit-as=mario', '--revision-    
range=44:45', '--server=http://172.16.4.175/reviewboard
--disable-proxy', '--summary=refs #2564 testcheckin for reviewboard', 
'--description=(In [45]) refs #2564 testcheckin for reviewboard. \npublish review', '']

There was an error creating this review request.

The repository path "http://sos35/svn/TestProject" is not in the list of known repositories on the server.
```

I've created a repository with this specific path in the reviewboard server. `svn info` gives this path as the rootpath of the svn repository. Running this script on the SVN repository server from the hooks folder.

So everything seems to be lined up for success, except for the previously mentioned exception.

Does anyone have any clue to solve this puzzle? Tried the .reviewboardrc file checkin in the project-root, with no success. Could be because this information in being overridden in the commandline of post-review.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the repository URL in ReviewBoard settings does not end with a slash. That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should ask your review-board administrator to add the root SVN path for you, I encountered this problem yesterday, and soon after the administrator add the SVN path for me, the post-review command worked.

However, I was faced with a new problem, the review request is successfully created but the diff file was not uploaded. I think the integration of review-board with SVN or possibly other SCMs really needs improvement.

Answer (score 2):

I also had similar issue but removing the tick from end of the path fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do you only see this problem when running the `post-review` script, or do you also get an error when performing the same operation through the web interface?

Remember that the `post-review` script uses variables set in your `.reviewboardrc` file as well as what you pass on the command line.  Make sure that you don't have conflicting options set in these two places.

I see that you have two types of URLs in your script: some use the `http://` format, and some use the `file://` format.  Do you have a single machine that is serving up both Subversion and ReviewBoard, or are these on separate servers?  How does the URL `http://sos35/svn/TestProject` relate to these systems?

Does the `file:///Repository/svn/TestProject` option describe a path on the machine that is running the script, or on the machine that is hosting ReviewBoard?  If this is a path on the machine that is running the script, then remember that it is not a valid path on any other server.  When a separate ReviewBoard server interprets that path, it won't match the URL that you used when configuring the repository (this most likely used a `http://` or `svn://` format URL).  The value passed to the `--repository-url=` option should exactly match the value listed in the "Path" field for the repository in ReviewBoard's admin interface.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Tried your suggestion and changed repository url to http://sos35/svn/TestProject. post-review hangs. When I let post-review hang for a while and end it with "no supported repository could be accessed at the supplied url". Tested if url is available. That seems to be the case. Enabled anonymous access but that didn't resolve anything. The repository-url is now equal to the repository path in RB.

Comment: @Mario- The error message you're getting is only displayed when `post-review` can't find any type of repository at the given address.  Does the command `svn info http://sos35/svn/TestProject` return successfully?  That's the command that `post-review` is using internally to detect the SVN repo.